# How can I disable the calendar agent from running on Mac OS X Lion?

Tags: macos, mac, calendar, osx-mountain-lion, calendar.app

I suppose that because because of the updated way that the Calendar application is integrated into the OS X system and the notification area the "calendar agent" needs to constantly run in the background on OS X ML.

I see it making a lot of requests when I debug the HTTP(s) requests on the system.
The requests stop if I do `killall CalendarAgent`:

#### How can I keep the calendar agent from running in the background?

P.S.: I also tried removing the calendar from the notification area without luck:

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can try like this:

```
launchctl unload /System/Library/LaunchAgents/com.apple.CalendarAgent.plist
```

If you want to make this permanent:

```
launchctl unload -w /System/Library/LaunchAgents/com.apple.CalendarAgent.plist
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: It doesn't work (with nor without sudo) `launchctl unload -w /System/Library/LaunchAgents/com.apple.CalendarAgent.plist` produces 
`launchctl: Error unloading: com.apple.CalendarAgent` because that's apparently not the agent that's running: `launchctl list|grep -i cal` and i get 
`76977   -       0x7fbf59e07fa0.anonymous.CalendarAgent`. I've force quit the agent, manually disabled it in the plist, remove all notifications, and calendar system preferences settings *yet it still returns*.

Comment: I also disable Calendar in the Spotlight Preferences yet still the CalendarAgent is magically starting.

Comment: It works. But then Apple Calendar is completely inhibited and crashes at start. I wonder if there is any way to start/use the service **just** when Calendar is running  (not exactly but something similar to how Windows allows to configure its services).

Answer (score 0):

Within 10.8.4 (12D78) doing:
 `launchctl unload /System/Library/LaunchAgents/com.apple.CalendarAgent.plist` 
***without*** `sudo`  works fine.

I only get:
`launchctl: Error unloading: com.apple.CalendarAgent`
with attempting `sudo....`

Comment: I can't tell if this is an answer or a comment...

Answer (score 0):

There may be a previously entered password for the process in your login Keychain. You may have to remove a key or certificate using the Keychain Access utility.

Answer (score 0):

Query *launchctl* for the label

```
$ launchctl list|grep -i calendar
725 0   com.apple.CalendarAgent
```

This means that it is running under your user account.

Running the following will remove it from your current login session:

```
$ launchctl remove com.apple.CalendarAgent
```

Check:

```
$ launchctl list|grep -i calendar
$
```

Return output should be nothing.

Comment: It works. But then Apple Calendar is completely inhibited and crashes at start. I wonder if there is any way to start/use the service **just** when Calendar is running  (not exactly but something similar to how Windows allows to configure its services).